# Seperate CSS animations on double background with sprites

Tags: css, animation, sprite

I have a button with two background images and use `background-blend-mode: overlay;` to blend them together.

**Image 1: A semi-transparent image containing smoke**

[image]

**Image 2: A sprite containing 2 states of the background**

[image]

When hovering the button an animation starts that scrolls **Image 1** infinitely from right to left, giving the illusion of smoke running through the button.

```
<a href="#"></a>

a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 68px;

  display: block;


  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/a52FaTn.png"), url("http://i.imgur.com/pCxkS4J.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;   
  background-blend-mode: overlay;

    animation: 16s linear 0s normal none infinite paused;

  animation-name: my-animation;
}

a:hover {
 animation-play-state: running; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes my-animation { from{background-position: 0px 0px, left 0px;} to{background-position: -590px 0px, left 0px;} }
@keyframes my-animation { from{background-position: 0px 0px, left 0px;} to{background-position: -590px 0px, left 0px;} }
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/663c2tj4/1/

So far so good. But now I want to make the background position for **image  2** switch to the right instantly (normally you would do this with regular background-position).

```
a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 68px;

  display: block;

  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/a52FaTn.png"), url("http://i.imgur.com/pCxkS4J.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;   
  background-blend-mode: overlay;

  animation: 16s linear 0s normal none infinite paused, none ;

  animation-name: my-animation;
}

a:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;   
  background-position: 0 0, right 0; // Gets overwritten by animation
}

@-webkit-keyframes my-animation { from{background-position: 0px 0px, left 0px;} to{background-position: -590px 0px, right 0px;} }
@keyframes my-animation { from{background-position: 0px 0px, left 0px;} to{background-position: -590px 0px, right 0px;} }
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/8b8fku0s/2/

As you can see it slowly moves **Image 2** to the right side, instead of doing it instantly like I want it to. Is it impossible to do using only one image?

**UPDATE:** I ended up using a different technique to get the result that I want. I used `background-blend-mode: luminosity;` with a white background to desaturate the image.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/8b8fku0s/5/

Answer (score 2):

Use a middle keyframe to make the second background move instantly

```
@keyframes my-animation { 
  from {background-position: 0px 0px, 0% 0px;} 
  49.99%{background-position: -295px 0px, 0% 0px;} 
  50%  {background-position: -295px 0px, right 0px;} 
  to   {background-position: -590px 0px, right 0px;} 
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zb0jgsa/)

But if you want the second background to be to the right all the animation time, it is easier. Just set the same value in the from and to keyframes:

```
@keyframes my-animation { 
  from {background-position:    0px 0px, right 0px;} 
  to   {background-position: -590px 0px, right 0px;} 
}
```

Comment: Doing that achieves the effect that I want but only after 8s (the animation duration is 16s) as seen here `animation: 16s linear 0s normal none infinite paused, none;`

I tried adding a second animaiton-duration parameter by doing `animation: 16s linear 0s normal none infinite paused, 0s;` but that doesn't work either.

https://jsfiddle.net/8b8fku0s/3/

Comment: I misunderstood you, sorry. Added another animation that I hope is what you want.